# Initialize Class without a variable

Tags: javascript

Lets say i have a class with a few methods inside. Usually i initialize it like this:

```
var myClassObj = new MyClass("Hello World");
myClassObj.SomeMethod();
```

I'm a little confused because I've seen examples where people just do this:

```
new MyClass("Hello World").SomeMethod();
```

Without using a variable, Now can someone help me understand why they do that? and what is the difference?

Comment: Its not a good code style to write like that , but you can, there is a no difference when you not need to use another method from this class, if you need then you should again write new MyClass and in that case you will have 2 initialization for same class which not so good

Comment: I would not code like the latter, but it's technically the same, if you don't need other properties of that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you will say this

```
var myClassObj = new MyClass("Hello World");
```

you will get a referance to that object which you can use later sometime.

but this

```
new MyClass("Hello World").SomeMethod();
```

you can use this object only here. If you want to use this object after sometime you cann't.

Comment: OK now i get it. Is it a bad practice to create Class instances without assigning them to variables?

Comment: @Adrao I don't think so, sometimes when you don't need to use it later why should I use a variable to store it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you save instance of MyClass to variable myClassObj and then call function.

In the second example, you create new instance without explicitly saving it and call method on it. The new instance is then "lost" after executing of method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference at all, except that you're saving yourself a line of code. Internally, a local instance variable is still being created.

The reason why you can do something like this

```
new MyClass("Hello World").SomeMethod();
```

is because the `MyClass` constructor is **returning a new instance of the class**, and therefore you can handle this return value as you may consider appropiate.

Answer (score -2):

Mybe you don't need using the variable and you have to call a function only once.
See the difference

```
new MyClass("Hello World").SomeMethod();
```

equals to:

```
var myClass = new MyClass("Hello World");
myClass.SomeMethod();
delete myClass;
```